# How to interpret column length error from ddplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to apply a function (more complex than the one used below, but I was trying to simplify) across two vectors. However, I receive the following error:

```
    mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
       Column `diff` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 777
```

I think I may be getting this error because the difference between rows results in one row less than the original dataframe, per some posts that I read. However, when I followed that advice and tried to add a vector to add 0/NA on the final line I received another error. Did I at least identify the source of the error correctly? Ideas? Thank you.

Original code:

```
     diff_df <- DF %>%
       group_by(DF$var1, DF$var2) %>%
       mutate(diff = map2(DF$duration, lead(DF$duration), `-`)) %>%
       as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Inside the `group_by` you don't `DF$`  just user `group_by(var1, var2)` and similarly nside the `mutate` too ie. `DF %>% group_by(var1, var2) %>% mutate(diff = duration - lead(duration))`

Comment: Huh, I did that to make the code more readable - but removing it got rid of the error! Why does simply removing the df name solve the issue?

Comment: It extracts the full column and breaks the grouping condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need `map2` to get the difference between the 'duration' and the `lead` of 'duration'.  It is vectorized.  `map2` will loop through each element of 'duration' with the corresponding element of `lead(duration)` which is unnecessary

```
DF %>% 
    group_by(var1, var2) %>% 
    mutate(diff = duration - lead(duration))
```

NOTE: When we extract the column with `DF$duration` after the `group_by`.  it is breaking the grouping condition and get the full dataset column.  Also, in the pipe, there is no need for `dataset$columnname`.  It should be `columnname` (However,in certain situations, when we want to get the full column for some comparison - it can be used)

Comment: Awesome - can't believe I didn't see that but makes perfect sense. Great example of why it's always good to get another set of eyes on your code. Thank you for catching such a silly mistake! (I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer and then I will.)